# Connecting to device with ZeroMQ stream fails, but Linux Sockets work

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, serial-port, zeromq

I have a serial device that is being converted to TCP/IP through a serial server. This seems to work correctly as other applications can connect this way.

In my application, I'm trying to use ZeroMQ ZMQ_STREAM to send a request for information to the device, and wait for a reply.

```
// from it's own thread: threadTx
zmq::socket_t soc_tx(zmq_ctx, ZMQ_STREAM);
soc_tx.connect("tcp://10.10.10.100:4003");

std::string msg("hello");
zmq::message_t zmsg(msg.c_str(), msg.size());
soc_tx.send(zmsg);
```

then from another thread:

```
// from another thread: threadRx
zmq::socket_t soc_rx(zmq_ctx, ZMQ_STREAM);
soc_rx.connect("tcp://10.10.10.100:4003");

zmq::message_t zrecv;
soc_rx.recv(&zrecv);
```

The `send` comes back as successful and I do receive a 0 length message which per documentation indicates a successful connection (or disconnect).

However, I never receive the reply to the original sent request. `soc_rx.recv()` will wait infinitely. Wireshark indicates a reply is being sent, it's just never received by ZeroMQ host.

I've also tried to receive on the same socket I opened for sending with no luck.

```
// from it's own thread: threadTx
zmq::socket_t soc(zmq_ctx, ZMQ_STREAM);
soc.connect("tcp://10.10.10.100:4003");

std::string msg("hello");
zmq::message_t zmsg(msg.c_str(), msg.size());
soc.send(zmsg);

while (true)
{
  zmq:message_t zrecv;
  soc.recv(&zrecv);
}
```

But still I only get the 0 length connection message and nothing else afterwards.

I thought this may be a configuration issue, but again, other applications work. I've also been able to successfully connect and both send and recv messages from the device using native Linux sockets.

```
uint16_t const PORT = 4003;
struct sockaddr_in address;
int sock = 0, valread;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
char buffer[1024] = {0};
if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
{
  return -1;
}

memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

// Convert IPv4 and IPv6 address from text to binary form
if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "10.10.10.100", &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0)
{
  std::cout << "> invalid address. address not supported" << std::endl;
  return nullptr;
}

if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
{
  std::cout << "> connection failed" << std::endl;
}

send(sock, out_buf, out_buf_size, 0);

std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

valread = recv(sock, buffer, 1024, 0);
```

And this works just fine.

For consistency with other applications in my system I'd love to use ZeroMQ for all socket communications, but is there a restriction preventing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some direction from @Jakub Piskorz below, I was able to come up with a viable solution. You need to send the zmq identity as the first frame for each message to the external device. However, getting the zmq identity did not work when using getsockopt(). I'm not sure if this is an issue with ZeroMQ or the CPP binder I'm using. However, I was able to get the ID by analyzing the 0 length message received by ZeroMQ.

An important detail I noticed as that I received a single, 0 length message that was a single frame (no identity frame) after every connect, follow by the 0 length connection message that was two frames (identity frame then the 0 length frame).

```
// init context and socket
zmq::context_t zctx;
zmq::socket_t zsock(zctx, ZMQ_STREAM);

// connect
zsock.connect(address);

// get socket identity from 0-length connect message
// this logic ignores any 0 length frames that may be received
bool idRecv = false;
zmq::message_t zid;
while (true)
{
  zmq::message_t zrecv;
  zsock.recv(&zrecv);
  if (0 < zrecv.size())
  {
    zid.copy(&zrecv);
    idRecv = true;
  }

  if (false == zrecv.more()
      && true == idRecv)
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

Then, using using [Multpart Messages](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Multipart-Messages) you need to send the identity frame first.

```
// send first frame
zsock.send(zid, ZMQ_SNDMORE);

// send next frame
std::string testMsg = "test";
zmq::message_t zmsgFrameTwo(testMsg.c_str(), testMsg.size());
zsock.send(zmsgFrameTwo);
```

This allows the message to make it across successfully.

Finally, make sure to receive both the identity frame and the reply to your request. They comes as separate frames.

```
// receive identity frame
zmq::message_t zrecvid;
zsock.recv(&zrecvid);

// receive reply frame
zmq::message_t zreply;
zsock.recv(&zreply);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using ZMQ_STREAM is a little tricky, but you should be able to use a single socket to communicate with an external TCP socket.

One disclaimer, I'll show examples using zmqpp library, but key point is not exact functions to call but rather how to correctly apply flow, so I hope you will be able to transform it to pure ZeroMQ.

Take a look at [zmq api docs](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-socket#toc19), Native pattern paragraph.

To initiate the connection with remote, after connect you need to obtain ZMQ_IDENTITY.

> To open a connection to a server, use the zmq_connect call, and then
>   fetch the socket identity using the ZMQ_IDENTITY zmq_getsockopt call.

```
zmqpp::socket tcp{context, zmqpp::socket_type::stream};
tcp.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:12345");
std::string identity = tcp.get<std::string>(zmqpp::socket_option::identity);
```

What is identity? Binary data. From [docs](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-getsockopt#toc16):

> Identity should be at least one byte and at most 255 bytes long.
>   Identities starting with binary zero are reserved for use by ØMQ
>   infrastructure.

After obtaining identity, you can receive on the socket to obtain zero-length message - it will indicate that connection has been established.

> When a connection is made, a zero-length message will be received by
>   the application.

**What I discovered, is when ZMQ_STREAM api docs mention zero-length message, it actually means message with 2 frames, first identity, second zero-length.**

Now, sending. What is missing in your code is to pass identity as first frame of the message. ZeroMQ engine will remove that and send only second frame (you can't add more frames to message).

> You must send one identity frame followed by one data frame. The
>   ZMQ_SNDMORE flag is required for identity frames but is ignored on
>   data frames.

```
zmqpp::message msg;
msg << identity;
msg << "Hello world";
tcp.send(msg);
```

Now you can wait for the response from remote, you'll either receive proper reply (message composed of 2 frames, first identity, second, what remote answered) or disconnection indication (zero-length message).

> When receiving TCP data, a ZMQ_STREAM socket shall prepend a message
>   part containing the identity of the originating peer to the message
>   before passing it to the application.
>
> Similarly, when the peer disconnects (or the connection is lost), a
>   zero-length message will be received by the application.

```
zmqpp::message msg;
tcp.receive(msg);

std::string r_ident;
msg >> r_ident;
std::string body;
msg >> body;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll test this and accept the answer if all works well. You're great!

Comment: I have been looking into this. unfortunately I've ran into some issues...

`zsoc.getsockopt(ZMQ_IDENTITY, &buf, &len)` fails everytime. So I can't seem to get the identity.